# How to over write and write in to a textfile by using Vbscript

Tags: vbscript

i created a text file "list.txt" in commonapplicationdatafolder by using the following VBscript.i am displaying some
values from a variable(strlist) by writing in to textfile.

```
Const Value = &H23&
Const PATH = "\Cape\ibs"

Dim fso                 ' File System Object
Dim spFile             ' Text File object to write
Dim objApplication      ' Application object
Dim objFolder           ' Folder object
Dim objFolderItem       ' FolderItem object

Set objApplication  = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objApplication.Namespace(Value)
Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self
sname = objFolderItem.Path & PATH & "\list.txt"
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set spFile = fso.CreateTextFile(sname, True)
spoFile.WriteLine(strlist)
spoFile.Close
```

Here are my doubts

1> Here before creating that file i need to delete the old existing "list.txt" Because during installation 
i always want to create the list file.  So i want to include code that removes any existing file(any old list.txt),
before creating the latest one.Here i did the following code

```
If fso.FileExists(sname) Then
    fso.DeleteFile sname, True
Else
    Set spFile = fso.CreateTextFile(sname, True)
    spoFile.WriteLine(strlist)
    Set objFolderItem = Nothing
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objApplication = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    spoFile.Close
 End If
```

Whats going on is it **will create folder first time,next time it will delete it** ,But i always want that file there(new fresh one with value from 'strlist' )
Can any one tell me the vbscript code to do that.Their i **removed Else part** also but only deletion going ,below things are not working means creation.

2>Here i was writing in to "list.txt" by using simply 'WriteLine' method(spoFile.WriteLine(strlist)),but i read somewhere that we need to use
'OpenTextFile'(Const ForWriting = 2) for writing,If that is the case what changes i need to do here,Is it mandatory?

Comment: 'OpenTextFile'(Const ForWriting = 2) for writing,Is it mandatory? or simply spoFile.WriteLine(strlist) is enough

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to move your delete or not delete decision before your write decision.

```
If fso.FileExists(sname) Then
    'you delete if you find it'
    fso.DeleteFile sname, True
End If
'you always write it anyway.'
Set spoFile = fso.CreateTextFile(sname, True)
spoFile.WriteLine(strlist)
Set objFolderItem = Nothing
Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objApplication = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
spoFile.Close
```

alternately to your question with Constant write values and making this a little (very little) bit faster, you might try the following:

```
If fso.FileExists(sname) Then
  Set spoFile = fso.OpenTextFile(sname, 2, True)
Else
  Set spoFile = fso.CreateTextFile(sname, True)
End If
' perform your write operations and close normally'
```

Comment: Thats fine,its working,,any bad logic are there in my coding,,i am new to vbscript

Comment: 'OpenTextFile'(Const ForWriting = 2) for writing,Is it mandatory? or simply spoFile.WriteLine(strlist) is enough

Comment: actually peter you only need the write constant for opening an existing text file. In your case you are deleting it and creating a new one. I've modified my answer to add an alternative for using the condition you are talking about.

Comment: Thats correct ,Delete operation is not required,simply .WriteLine(strlist) will overwrite previous file.But the requirement is like this

Answer (score 1):

```
' copy in flash drive 
 Const Removable = 1 
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set colDrives = FSO.Drives 
For Each Drive in colDrives 
If Drive.DriveType = Removable then 
fso.copyfile "filename.vbs" , Drive.DriveLetter&":\" 
End if 
Next
```